# Create a secret "Ninja" badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I am suggesting a new badge entitled `Ninja`.  This would be a gold badge.  And in keeping with the secrecy of true Ninjas, the badge should not be mentioned anywhere except a user's profile page (and after implementation, delete this request to protect that).

What are the requirements for awarding the badge?  Well, it would be a subjective badge to which the SE staff would award said badge to the user in question based upon their contribution to either the community or SE in general.  Basically, if a user goes above and beyond, or makes a significant back-channel contribution to the community, they can be deemed *ninja-worthy*.

Comment: So, in a sense, kinda like the [alleged hacker badge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/ "I always pay heed to the date of that blog post, myself.") mentioned back in '09?

Comment: @Grace: Except that was a joke post, and I'm actually serious about this implementation...  But yes, along the same note...

Comment: I already have this badge. It's **so** ninja that it's invisible even to *me*.

Comment: Only moderators can see the Ninja badge.  We're samurai.

Comment: @Brant: Maybe you actually have a Heisenbadge. It exists only as long as you aren't looking at it.

Comment: @gnostradamus: a Heisenbadge can exist, but you could either know what it's awarded for, or who has achieved it. So, while I'm not entirely sure of your explanation, I'm pretty sure @ircmaxell has achieved that one.

Comment: People would know you have the badge when you walk into a room and a kitteh starts purring.

Comment: FWIW: just got the "badges" badge, in part thanks to this question. Another 83 up-votes, and I'll actually have *a* "ninja" badge...

Comment: @Shog9: Not any more. random is a big stick in the mud. =P

Comment: Only if Shogginton had 99 other answers in the ninja tag @gno

Comment: @Shog: only if those 100 upvotes are spread over 20 questions with the tag :)

Comment: Awesome!! Now I want it

Comment: I think this would be a great idea, it's the way for SE (as an org) to say "hey, thanks for doing this" and the comment for that badge would indicate what the reason was (custom reason every time).  Of course, we'd have to immediately downvote any question on meta asking to reveal ninja badges on profiles.  Maybe it should be called "fight-club" ("the first rule of fight-club is") and if someone *does* talk about it, the badge is revoked.  Seriously.

Comment: Am I the only one all ready having that badge? Just Kidding! Sounds like a great idea to be able to award something unique to special contributors

Answer (score 49):

Because you posted this suggestion, this badge can never be implemented without first killing you and everyone who has seen this. Nice work.

Comment: I'm typing this with my eyes closed

Comment: @Juan: I'm *reading* that with my eyes closed.

Comment: @Bill, there is software for doing that, so I believe you (*crosses Bill off the list*)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Eyes wide shut eh? :P

Comment: Braille keyboard. Every Ninja should have one.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/ basically make this a [status-completed]? :) It's a physical badge, not shown to anyone unless you do.