# How can we see who was awarded hidden badges?

Tags: discussion

Initial question: **Is there a hidden Hacker badge?**

I was reading questions on meta about the Generalist badge, and I noticed someone talking about "the Hacker badge", a badge he styled as "the Duke Nukem Forever of StackExchange".

Which is the right explanation:

- Is there such a thing?
- Is it the former name of a currently existing badge?
- Is it an idea that got dropped into the tarpit of time everlasting?
- Did he smoke pot?

Edit: I found the answer on [Should there be a badge for cheating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8914/should-there-be-a-badge-for-cheating) which states there is such a badge.

**New question**:

How can we see if it has been awarded *to other users* if it is a hidden badge? Is there some condition to see it (have enough reputation, be a moderator?)

Comment: I'm guessing it would be visible on the user's profile page.

Comment: You've just earned a hidden badge! (But you can't see it, of course.)

Comment: @Grigory M Actually, I assumed the user who got the badged could see it, but I was thinking about other users. I'll edit my question to point this out, thanks for the help.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Once you know the answer, this question seems silly, but before you know the answer, it's reasonable.

Comment: @popular this badge was never implemented and probably won't be at this point, so... done and done.

Comment: So given Jeff Atwood's definitive answer, there is conflicting information on Meta. The second link my question quotes is mistaken, giving rise to my question. The answer is therefore: *THERE IS NO HIDDEN BADGE, IT WAS A POSSIBILITY BUT IT WAS NEVER IMPLEMENTED AND PROBABLY NEVER WILL BE.* This by the way involves facts and references, and don't sollicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling or extended discussion, and anyway I'd think that a question that is clearly argumented, well formatted and backed up by fact should not be closed that easily. My own view, though.

Answer (score 5):

There are no hidden badges implemented. One was planned, but...

> this badge was never implemented and probably won't be at this point
>   – [Jeff Atwood♦ Sep 11 '11 at 7:50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104414/how-can-we-see-who-was-awarded-hidden-badges#comment-271389)

Comment: ircmaxell claimed in his [moderator nomination](http://stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-8054342) that he is a recipient of the "ninja" hidden badge.

Comment: @Problem Huh... I wonder what that means, exactly. Edited to say at least that there are none "implemented", since that seems safer.

Comment: @Problem See his featured request [Create a secret “Ninja” badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81731/create-a-secret-ninja-badge), though it could also be interpreted more interestingly.